# dplyr and previous observations

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to run a bunch of linear models on each unique identifier, but first I need to do a check.  For each unique id and year, I need to check that there are at least 24 months of previous monthly data, but not more than 60 months.  So when I run the regression it should include between 24 - 60 observations of previous month (years) data for each year of each individual.  If there are less than 24 months of data for that year, the year is dropped for that individual, but if there are more than 60, then only the 60 months are used.

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29554247/dplyr-and-multiple-linear-models) (thanks @akrun) post, I was able to setup the linear models for each individual, run them, and then output the beta as the sum of both betas.  The problem is that this only runs the regression on the current year (12 obs) and not the previous 24-60.

Edit : I realized the dput was wrong...sorry

Single cusip dput:

```
    tdata <- structure(list(cusip = c(101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 
101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 
101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 
101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 
101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 
101L, 101L, 101L), date = c(19901130L, 19901031L, 19900928L, 
19900831L, 19900731L, 19900629L, 19900531L, 19900430L, 19900330L, 
19900228L, 19900131L, 19891229L, 19891130L, 19891031L, 19890929L, 
19890831L, 19890731L, 19890630L, 19890531L, 19890428L, 19890331L, 
19890228L, 19890131L, 19881230L, 19881130L, 19881031L, 19880930L, 
19880831L, 19880729L, 19880630L, 19880531L, 19880429L, 19880331L, 
19880229L, 19880129L, 19871231L, 19871130L, 19871030L, 19870930L, 
19870831L, 19870731L, 19870630L, 19870529L, 19870430L, 19870331L, 
19870227L, 19870130L, 19861231L, 19861128L, 19861031L, 19860930L, 
19860829L, 19860731L), fyear = c("1990", "1990", "1990", "1990", 
"1990", "1990", "1990", "1990", "1990", "1990", "1990", "1989", 
"1989", "1989", "1989", "1989", "1989", "1989", "1989", "1989", 
"1989", "1989", "1989", "1988", "1988", "1988", "1988", "1988", 
"1988", "1988", "1988", "1988", "1988", "1988", "1988", "1987", 
"1987", "1987", "1987", "1987", "1987", "1987", "1987", "1987", 
"1987", "1987", "1987", "1986", "1986", "1986", "1986", "1986", 
"1986"), month = c("11", "10", "09", "08", "07", "06", "05", 
"04", "03", "02", "01", "12", "11", "10", "09", "08", "07", "06", 
"05", "04", "03", "02", "01", "12", "11", "10", "09", "08", "07", 
"06", "05", "04", "03", "02", "01", "12", "11", "10", "09", "08", 
"07", "06", "05", "04", "03", "02", "01", "12", "11", "10", "09", 
"08", "07"), ret = c("0.117647", "0.030303", "-0.161017", "-0.186207", 
"-0.131737", "0.128378", "0.027778", "-0.162791", "0.131579", 
"0.178295", "-0.091549", "0.163934", "-0.089552", "0.007519", 
"0.117647", "0.155340", "0.211765", "0.024096", "0.338710", "0.377778", 
"0.071429", "-0.176471", "0.378378", "-0.026316", "-0.050000", 
"-0.047619", "-0.086957", "-0.061224", "0.088889", "-0.062500", 
"-0.040000", "-0.056604", "0.081633", "0.042553", "-0.096154", 
"0.238095", "-0.263158", "-0.393617", "-0.160714", "0.400000", 
"-0.090909", "-0.200000", "-0.098361", "-0.152778", "0.000000", 
"0.107692", "0.460674", "-0.101010", "-0.019802", "0.246914", 
"-0.052632", "0.179310", "-0.064516"), ewretd = c(0.035468, -0.057155, 
-0.080468, -0.108911, -0.025732, 0.005359, 0.045675, -0.028117, 
0.021315, 0.015434, -0.046408, -0.012375, -0.0058, -0.049934, 
0.005532, 0.018626, 0.031017, -0.007744, 0.025054, 0.029089, 
0.01806, 0.002988, 0.062124, 0.018872, -0.036484, -0.011485, 
0.016951, -0.025001, 0.000289, 0.047677, -0.017671, 0.014016, 
0.03569, 0.060265, 0.077392, 0.026065, -0.05085, -0.272248, -0.015876, 
0.014544, 0.035123, 0.021487, 0.000573, -0.017709, 0.036283, 
0.074612, 0.117565, -0.034609, -0.006263, 0.023777, -0.059071, 
0.023269, -0.073128), lagewretd = c(-0.004526, 0.035468, -0.057155, 
-0.080468, -0.108911, -0.025732, 0.005359, 0.045675, -0.028117, 
0.021315, 0.015434, -0.046408, -0.012375, -0.0058, -0.049934, 
0.005532, 0.018626, 0.031017, -0.007744, 0.025054, 0.029089, 
0.01806, 0.002988, 0.062124, 0.018872, -0.036484, -0.011485, 
0.016951, -0.025001, 0.000289, 0.047677, -0.017671, 0.014016, 
0.03569, 0.060265, 0.077392, 0.026065, -0.05085, -0.272248, -0.015876, 
0.014544, 0.035123, 0.021487, 0.000573, -0.017709, 0.036283, 
0.074612, 0.117565, -0.034609, -0.006263, 0.023777, -0.059071, 
0.023269)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-53L), .Names = c("cusip", "date", "fyear", "month", "ret", "ewretd", 
"lagewretd"))
```

dplyr code :

```
res1 <- tdata %>%  
  group_by(cusip, fyear) %>% 
  arrange(desc(date)) %>% 
  mutate(n=n()) %>%
  do(data.frame(., beta=ifelse(.$n > 2,
   sum(coef(lm(ret~ewretd+lagewretd, data=.))[-1]), NA)))
```

Update 2 : 04/13/2015

Here is a `for` loop that I could think of that would solve the problem, but again, `for` loops in R are not the most efficient solution.

```
for (i : unique(cusip)){
  for (j : unique(fyear)){
    check <- filter(tdata, fyear == i & fyear == i-1 & fyear == i-2 & fyear == i-3 & fyear == i-4)
    ifelse(length(check$month < 24), tdata$beta == NA, if(length(check$month >= 60)){
                                                         arrange(check, desc(date)),
                                                         filter(check, month[1:60,]),
                                                         check$beta <- sum(coef(lm(ret~ewretd+lagewretd, data = check))[-1])), 
                                                         left_join(tdata, check, by=c("cusip", fyear == j))}
```

Update 3 : Full sample set

This includes all obs, which is fairly large (323mb)

[Full Sample](https://www.dropbox.com/s/u3mvxn50d65tsjn/testing.csv?dl=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the long run, you probably want to use proper dates. I've made a small step in that direction by converting `fyear` from character to integer.

```
library(dplyr)

## convert fyear to a proper number and then exploit for sorting
tdata <- tdata %>%
  mutate(fyear = fyear %>% as.integer) %>%
  arrange(fyear, month)
```

Then I make a `tbl` summarized at the level of `fyear`, computing how many cumulative months of data you would have available for fitting a model. (I'm dragging `cusip` around but since your data only includes one `cusip`, I can't be sure that this is all working correctly.)

```
## figure out cumulative months available for each year (for each cusip)
yearstuff <- tdata %>%  
  group_by(cusip, fyear) %>% 
  summarize(n = n()) %>% 
  mutate(n_cum = cumsum(n))
yearstuff
# Source: local data frame [5 x 4]
# Groups: cusip
# 
#   cusip fyear  n n_cum
# 1   101  1986  6     6
# 2   101  1987 12    18
# 3   101  1988 12    30
# 4   101  1989 12    42
# 5   101  1990 11    53
```

I don't find the model fitting to be a very natural task for `dplyr`, since it doesn't fit nicely into the `group_by` paradigm. Instead I drive things off of `yearstuff`, using `plyr::ddply()`, and pull the data I need for each `cusip` * `fyear` combination. I decline to fit a model if there is not enough data and if there is too much data, I only take the most recent 60 months.

```
## iterate over rows of yearstuff (for each cusip)
models <- plyr::ddply(yearstuff, ~ cusip + fyear, function(y) {
  if(y$n_cum < 24) {
    c('(Intercept)' = NA_real_, ewretd = NA_real_, lagewretd = NA_real_)
  } else {
    my_dat <- tdata %>%
      filter(cusip == y$cusip, fyear <= y$fyear) %>%
      mutate(rn = row_number(desc(date)))
    lm(ret ~ ewretd + lagewretd, my_dat, subset = rn < 61) %>% coef
  }
})
models
#   cusip fyear (Intercept)   ewretd  lagewretd
# 1   101  1986          NA       NA         NA
# 2   101  1987          NA       NA         NA
# 3   101  1988 -0.01138861 1.614342 0.14885911
# 4   101  1989  0.02467139 1.878295 0.00598857
# 5   101  1990  0.02529068 1.900389 0.05766020
```

This leaves you with the estimated coefficients to use as you wish. I think this should scale to multiple `cusip`s but who knows?. Also this dataset doesn't contain more than 60 months. You should obviously do some spot checks of these results "by hand"!

Comment: Thanks...the issue I'm having with your first step is that because a year doesn't have 24-60 months of prior observations means it shouldn't be excluded, because multiple years prior could depend up on these observations.  That is why the check needs to work before the regression is applied....I've updated the answer with the full data set if you want to take a crack at it I'd apprecaite it :)

Comment: When you say first step, do you refer to the formation of `yearstuff` or the `if` part inside `ddply()`? I think (at least) one of us is misunderstanding the other. I loop over unique combinations of `cusip` and `fyear` and take all data from `tdata` for that `cusip`, up to and including that `fyear`. If there's enough, I fit the model (but don't use more than 60 months). There is no global sense in which a year is either included or excluded. It depends on the context.

Comment: Ok, I see what is going on now.  This is going to take a vey long time with 1.1m obs.  Any way to speed it up?  This is why I was working in `dplyr`

Comment: After running this on the full data set for several hours, i got this message `Error in do.ply(i) : task 98081 failed - "0 (non-NA) cases"`  Any idea?  I appreciate your help.

Comment: Ooh, did not realize how large the full dataset is. You'll want to code very defensively then. Writing stuff to file as you go and/or putting the lm call inside try, so a single error doesn't leave you with nothing. Then maybe you can just wait plyr out. But if this not a one-time thing, then speed matters. Maybe you should look for a data.table solution? Wonder if it has a way to express your rolling usage of monthly data?