# data table option for check and batch of linear models

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

I'm wondering if there is a `data.table` option for batch processing linear models from a data set with a check first.

I need to run a bunch of linear models on each unique identifier, but first I need to do a check. For each unique id and year, I need to check that there are at least 24 months of previous monthly data, but not more than 60 months. So when I run the regression it should include between 24 - 60 observations of previous month (years) data for each year of each individual. If there are less than 24 months of data for that year, the year is dropped for that individual, but if there are more than 60, then only the 60 months are used.

Thanks to this (thanks @akrun) post, I was able to setup the linear models for each individual, run them, and then output the beta as the sum of both betas. The problem is that this only runs the regression on the current year (12 obs) and not the previous 24-60.

Previous Post : [dplyr and previous observations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29618531/dplyr-and-previous-observations)

I was hoping for a `dplyr` option, but it doesn't seem that it will work, and the `ddply` method in the post and below takes hours to run.  However, I need to run this multiple times on various data sets that range in the 1.1 million obs.

dput example :

```
   tdata <- structure(list(cusip = c(101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 
101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 
101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 
101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 
101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 
101L, 101L, 101L), date = c(19901130L, 19901031L, 19900928L, 
19900831L, 19900731L, 19900629L, 19900531L, 19900430L, 19900330L, 
19900228L, 19900131L, 19891229L, 19891130L, 19891031L, 19890929L, 
19890831L, 19890731L, 19890630L, 19890531L, 19890428L, 19890331L, 
19890228L, 19890131L, 19881230L, 19881130L, 19881031L, 19880930L, 
19880831L, 19880729L, 19880630L, 19880531L, 19880429L, 19880331L, 
19880229L, 19880129L, 19871231L, 19871130L, 19871030L, 19870930L, 
19870831L, 19870731L, 19870630L, 19870529L, 19870430L, 19870331L, 
19870227L, 19870130L, 19861231L, 19861128L, 19861031L, 19860930L, 
19860829L, 19860731L), fyear = c("1990", "1990", "1990", "1990", 
"1990", "1990", "1990", "1990", "1990", "1990", "1990", "1989", 
"1989", "1989", "1989", "1989", "1989", "1989", "1989", "1989", 
"1989", "1989", "1989", "1988", "1988", "1988", "1988", "1988", 
"1988", "1988", "1988", "1988", "1988", "1988", "1988", "1987", 
"1987", "1987", "1987", "1987", "1987", "1987", "1987", "1987", 
"1987", "1987", "1987", "1986", "1986", "1986", "1986", "1986", 
"1986"), month = c("11", "10", "09", "08", "07", "06", "05", 
"04", "03", "02", "01", "12", "11", "10", "09", "08", "07", "06", 
"05", "04", "03", "02", "01", "12", "11", "10", "09", "08", "07", 
"06", "05", "04", "03", "02", "01", "12", "11", "10", "09", "08", 
"07", "06", "05", "04", "03", "02", "01", "12", "11", "10", "09", 
"08", "07"), ret = c("0.117647", "0.030303", "-0.161017", "-0.186207", 
"-0.131737", "0.128378", "0.027778", "-0.162791", "0.131579", 
"0.178295", "-0.091549", "0.163934", "-0.089552", "0.007519", 
"0.117647", "0.155340", "0.211765", "0.024096", "0.338710", "0.377778", 
"0.071429", "-0.176471", "0.378378", "-0.026316", "-0.050000", 
"-0.047619", "-0.086957", "-0.061224", "0.088889", "-0.062500", 
"-0.040000", "-0.056604", "0.081633", "0.042553", "-0.096154", 
"0.238095", "-0.263158", "-0.393617", "-0.160714", "0.400000", 
"-0.090909", "-0.200000", "-0.098361", "-0.152778", "0.000000", 
"0.107692", "0.460674", "-0.101010", "-0.019802", "0.246914", 
"-0.052632", "0.179310", "-0.064516"), ewretd = c(0.035468, -0.057155, 
-0.080468, -0.108911, -0.025732, 0.005359, 0.045675, -0.028117, 
0.021315, 0.015434, -0.046408, -0.012375, -0.0058, -0.049934, 
0.005532, 0.018626, 0.031017, -0.007744, 0.025054, 0.029089, 
0.01806, 0.002988, 0.062124, 0.018872, -0.036484, -0.011485, 
0.016951, -0.025001, 0.000289, 0.047677, -0.017671, 0.014016, 
0.03569, 0.060265, 0.077392, 0.026065, -0.05085, -0.272248, -0.015876, 
0.014544, 0.035123, 0.021487, 0.000573, -0.017709, 0.036283, 
0.074612, 0.117565, -0.034609, -0.006263, 0.023777, -0.059071, 
0.023269, -0.073128), lagewretd = c(-0.004526, 0.035468, -0.057155, 
-0.080468, -0.108911, -0.025732, 0.005359, 0.045675, -0.028117, 
0.021315, 0.015434, -0.046408, -0.012375, -0.0058, -0.049934, 
0.005532, 0.018626, 0.031017, -0.007744, 0.025054, 0.029089, 
0.01806, 0.002988, 0.062124, 0.018872, -0.036484, -0.011485, 
0.016951, -0.025001, 0.000289, 0.047677, -0.017671, 0.014016, 
0.03569, 0.060265, 0.077392, 0.026065, -0.05085, -0.272248, -0.015876, 
0.014544, 0.035123, 0.021487, 0.000573, -0.017709, 0.036283, 
0.074612, 0.117565, -0.034609, -0.006263, 0.023777, -0.059071, 
0.023269)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-53L), .Names = c("cusip", "date", "fyear", "month", "ret", "ewretd", 
"lagewretd"))
```

ddply method :

```
library(dplyr)

## convert fyear to a proper number and then exploit for sorting
tdata <- tdata %>%
  mutate(fyear = fyear %>% as.integer) %>%
  arrange(fyear, month)

## figure out cumulative months available for each year (for each cusip)
yearstuff <- tdata %>%  
  group_by(cusip, fyear) %>% 
  summarize(n = n()) %>% 
  mutate(n_cum = cumsum(n))

## iterate over rows of yearstuff (for each cusip)
models <- plyr::ddply(yearstuff, ~ cusip + fyear, function(y) {
  if(y$n_cum < 24) {
    c('(Intercept)' = NA_real_, ewretd = NA_real_, lagewretd = NA_real_)
  } else {
    my_dat <- tdata %>%
      filter(cusip == y$cusip, fyear <= y$fyear) %>%
      mutate(rn = row_number(desc(date)))
    lm(ret ~ ewretd + lagewretd, my_dat, subset = rn < 61) %>% coef
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write a seperate function for all the calculations you do to get the coefficients. Then you can use either `plyr`, `dplyr` or `data.table`. You should probably rerun the benchmarktests below with larger datasets.

```
# function to get coefficients 
# (further optimization should probably focus on improving this function)
get_coefs <- function(.cusip, .fyear, .n_cum){
  if(.n_cum < 24) {
    data_frame(`(Intercept)` = NA_real_, ewretd = NA_real_, lagewretd = NA_real_)
  } else {
    my_dat <- tdata %>%
      filter(cusip == .cusip, fyear <= .fyear) %>%
      mutate(rn = row_number(desc(date)))
    lm(ret ~ ewretd + lagewretd, my_dat, subset = rn < 61) %>% 
      coef %>% 
      as.list %>% 
      as_data_frame
  }
}
require(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  models_plyr <- plyr::ddply(yearstuff, ~ cusip + fyear, function(y)
    get_coefs(y$cusip, y$fyear, y$n_cum))
  ,
  models_dplyr <- yearstuff %>% 
    group_by(cusip, fyear) %>%
    do(get_coefs(.$cusip, .$fyear, .$n_cum))
  ,
  models_dt <- as.data.table(as.data.frame(yearstuff))[, get_coefs(cusip, fyear, n_cum), by = list(cusip, fyear)]
)
##      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
## 12.69178 13.29136 13.62600 13.45849 13.67471 16.73910   100   c
## 12.45302 12.94036 13.33589 13.14721 13.59907 14.73485   100  b 
## 10.66120 11.09856 11.43126 11.21593 11.45625 13.69591   100 a  
all.equal(models_plyr %>% data.frame, 
          models_dplyr %>% data.frame)
## [1] TRUE
all.equal(models_plyr %>% data.frame, 
          models_dt %>% data.frame) 
## [1] TRUE
```

Comment: I believe for benchmarking it should it appropriate to prepare the object in advanced to not include `as.data.table(as.data.frame(yearstuff))` in timing.

Comment: @JanGorecki: I guess that depends on the remaining workflow of the OP. If conversion to `data.table` and then back to `data.frame` are necessary they should probably be included in benchmarking. Otherwise they probably should not. Anyway, I doubt that the conversions between `data.table` and `data.frame` is the major bottleneck in these calculations.

Comment: then the `setDT` or `setDF` should be used, which doesn't need to take copy - it has significant impact on bigger sets. This is not bottleneck here but benchmark on unequal processes in worthless. Just wraps your third call into `setDF(yearstuff_dt[...])` and you should get what you need without mentioned overhead.

Comment: @shadow Thanks!  This is exactly what I was looking for.  Unfortunately, because the data set is so large (1.1m obs) this still takes 2 hours with `dplyr`.  I guess I'll just have to be patient.