# How to run rolling regressions in a data.table and store the coefficients in a column?

Tags: r, data.table, zoo

Calculating rolling means is easy:

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)
DT <- data.table(Y = rnorm(1000), X = rnorm(1000), 
       key.group = rep(c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), each = 250))
DT[, Average.Y := rollapply(Y, width = 12, mean)]
```

But how do I run rolling regressions (by group) with `data.table` and store the coefficient of interest, without extracting the values to another object if possible? Is this feasible?

This attempt does not work:

```
DT[, coefficient := rollapply(.SD, 20, function(x) { 
          the.coefficient <- lm(Y ~ X, data = x)$coefficients[2];
          return(the.coefficient)}), by = key.group]
```

Comment: possible duplicate: Fast linear regression by group http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29803993/fast-linear-regression-by-group