# data.table apply a user defined function over rows

Tags: r, data.table

I have a huge data.table dt (almost 1.5 million rows)
let say 
i want to apply a user defined function growth.ls to its rows, where scols (some columns in dt) are the arguments as

```
growth.ls <- function(values){
  if (any(!is.finite(values)) || any(values <= 0)) return(NA_real_)
  exp(lm(log(values) ~ (seq_along(values)))$coefficients[[2]] - 1) * 100}
dt[, `:=`(var = growth.ls(as.numeric(.SD))), .SDcols = scols, by = 1:nrow(dt)]
```

this process takes a very long time, I do not know if the problem is the growth.ls, or i am because i am using by: 1:nrow(dt).

Comment: Yeah, that is not a good way to use a data.frame or data.table -- you are splitting up into a large number of rows, then coercing each row from a data.table to a numeric vector. Try using `melt` to put your data in long form instead maybe

Comment: you can probably speed things up a lot by using `lm.fit`; pre-allocating your model matrix (`X <- cbind(1,1:ncol(dt))`); and possibly even computing the regression slope [directly](http://www.statisticshowto.com/how-to-find-a-linear-regression-slope/) - you can precompute everything except sum(y) and sum(x*y) ...

Comment: Is it possible to provide an example so i could try it.

Comment: not right now. maybe someone else will come along and provide one.

Comment: relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29803993/fast-linear-regression-by-group/29806540#29806540 and a rolling version: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/125509/rolling-regressions-in-r

Comment: x <- data.table(y = letters[1:4],
           x1990 = c(1,1,1,2),
           x1991 = c(2,1,1,1),
           x1992 = c(3,3,3,0.5),
           x1993 = c(5,2,2,4),
           x1994 = c(7,3, 5, NA_real_),
           x1995 = c(9, 8, 10,1))
if applied growth.ls to year columns (x1990: x1995) 
apply(x[, paste0("x", 1990:1995), with = FALSE], 1, growth.ls)
# [1] 56.88514 53.77536 58.00203       NA
I want to use this concept to produce a column in x called "growth" using data.table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this (using multicores with data.table):

```
library(parallel)
cl = makeCluster(detectCores())
choose_cols = startsWith(colnames(df),'x')

df[,growth := unlist(parApply(cl, .SD, 1, growth.ls), .SDcols = choose_cols]
```

Comment: Seriously i do not know what to say except thank you very much for ur help an support. parallel is powerful and consumed all processor up to 99% and done all job in 5 mins.

Comment: Glad to know. Accept the answer if it solves your problem. It helps us in keeping track. :)